# Understanding Absoluteness

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Godel's Constructible Universe  is defined by transfinite recursion as follows:

$$ L_{0}:=\varnothing .$$
$${\displaystyle L_{\alpha +1}:=\operatorname {Def} (L_{\alpha }).} $$
If ${\displaystyle \lambda } $ is a limit ordinal, then: $$L_{\lambda }:=\bigcup _{\alpha <\lambda }L_{\alpha }$$ and:
$${\displaystyle L:=\bigcup _{\alpha \in \mathbf {Ord} }}L_{\alpha}$$
Where

$\operatorname {Def} (X):={\Bigl \{}\{y\mid y\in X{\text{ and }}(X,\in )\models \Phi (y,z_{1},\ldots ,z_{n})\}~{\Big |}~\Phi {\text{ is a first-order formula and }}z_{1},\ldots ,z_{n}\in X{\Bigr \}}.$

I'm reading through Jech's 'Axiom of Choice' on the Constructible Universe and am trying to understand why $$(V= L)^L$$
The proof is to show that '$x$ is constructible' is an absolute formula, and then to state that $$(V=L)^L \iff (V=L)^V$$
By which the result follows by absoluteness. However this is the problem I'm having: Surely, (a) It is trivially true that $L$ believes that all sets are constructible, (how on earth could it not?) and (b) surely it is trivially false that $(V=L)^V$, after all, $V$ is constructed without the stipulation that sets must be definable, whereas $L$ is. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Don't apply absoluteness to $V=L $. Rather, for $x\in L $, consider the statement $(x\in L)^L $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is not trivial at all.

The point here is that $x\in L$ is a $\Delta_1$ formula, so it is indeed absolute and $L^L=L^V=L$.

But this is not necessarily true for other classes, even if they seem "very definable". For example, the class $\rm HOD$, which is the class sets which are hereditarily definable from the ordinals, is also an inner model of $\sf ZFC$, but $\rm HOD^{HOD}$ is not necessarily $\rm HOD^V$. In fact, there can be an inner model $M$ such that $\mathrm{HOD}\subsetneq\mathrm{HOD}^M$.

So the fact that the formula for $L$ is "simple" is a *very* important fact.

Secondly, there is the point that $V$ and $L$ are constructed in very different ways. And even if you look at the von Neumann hierarchy *inside $L$*, it will still be very different from the constructible hierarchy itself (although the two will often coincide).

Comment: Thanks Asaf, I see now why $(V=L)^L$ is non-trivial. Can you comment on why $(V=L)^V$ is true. It seems to me that $V$ can believe that there are non-constructible sets.

Comment: Yes, for example, if the axiom of choice fails, then there is definitely a non-constructible set.